# How to remove type conflicts with a library and executable that reference each other?

Tags: c#, types, reference, alias

I have two different files, Foo1.exe and Foo2.dll.

When I try to use an object declared in Foo2.dll in Foo1.exe, everything works as expected.

When I try to use an object declared in Foo1.exe in Foo2.dll, everything compiles as expected.

But when I try to pass an object from Foo1.exe to Foo2.dll, Foo1.exe cannot compile because it has a type conflicting with an object in Foo2.dll which is not actually there, but was just referenced from Foo1.exe.

How do I make it so Foo2.dll can reference Foo1.exe, but the types do not cause conflictions when compiling Foo1.exe?

The actual error message is `The type Foo in Foo1.cs conflicts with the imported type Foo in Foo2.cs`

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have somehow managed to have Foo1.exe reference a different copy of Foo2.dll that doesn't reference Foo1.exe. Because the C# compiler will prevent you from doing what you're trying to do - which is create circular references.

So the fact that yours is even compiling is a fluke and you should try a different approach.

You need to isolate the classes that are common to both Foo1.exe and Foo2.dll into a third assembly, Foo3.dll which is referenced by both. Then Foo3.dll should reference *neither* Foo1.exe or Foo2.dll.

Comment: That probably happened because I was doing a bit of hacky stuff to the Foo1.exe and caused a circular reference. What should I do if I cannot remove the class from Foo1.exe, but wish to still pass objects from Foo1.exe to Foo2.dll without conflicts? Is this even possible? In order words, can I do something to Foo2.dll to keep it from causing a circular reference?

Comment: You can define an interface IFoo in Foo2.dll, then have methods in Foo2.dll accept IFoo instead of Foo. Then have class Foo in Foo1.exe implement IFoo. That way all Foo2 has to know about is IFoo and no circular reference is needed.

Comment: Except with my hacky methods, I don't think I can just create IFoo for Foo2.dll exactly so that Foo in Foo1.exe can implement it perfectly. Is there way to create an interface of Foo just by directly reflecting everything in Foo without typing it out into code exactly? Thanks!

Comment: No not really. I think you're realizing the benefits of SOLID the hard way. In the short term you may want to just incorporate Foo2.dll into your main Foo1.exe project. In the long term you may want to rewrite. (SOLID - http://bit.ly/mGXwLu)

Comment: Ah, well thanks for your answers! I will take all of this information and try to take a more SOLID approach to the issue. Thanks again!